# R use input filename as output filename

Tags: r, filepath

I would like to have a R filename have the same input name but with a few characters attached to the end, such as

`input = data`

`output= data_addition`

Here is what I have so far:

```
input= file.path("E:/dir/folder/inputName.csv")
name = basename(input)
data = read.csv(file,skip=10)
```

And I'm not sure what to write in the `write.csv(data,????)`. I've done similiar operations with Python but not in R.

Comment: You can use `write.csv(data, "file.name.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` like this:

```
outname <- paste0(substr(input, start = 1, stop = nchar(input) - 4), "your_addition.csv")
write.csv(data, outname)
```